# Direct row count of a file(ByteStream ) - JAVA

Tags: java

I have a multipart file as a ByteStream in my class, for which I wish to count the number of records in it.

The file uploaded would either be a text/CSV format with records like:

```
number1,note1
number1,note2
number3,note3
...
```

My main requirement is that, I do not store this file anywhere.

So I can not use `FileReader` or `BufferedReader`.

Is there a way to count the rows of this ByteStream directly?

Comment: In which way do you receive the file? As a String or an InputStream or ...?

Comment: Yes. And the file system is something which I cannot access.

Comment: Neither. I get as `Multipart file` from `js` to my `controller` and pass it to my `service` class.

Comment: 1. You don't have a file. You have a stream. 2. Define 'I get the file from user system'. 3. State *why* you need the line counf of a file you otherwise don't do anything with except retransmit.

Comment: @Mike I suggest you If you have Java 8+ then use this for count the number of line in txt file `Path pathL = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
long lineCount = Files.lines(path).count();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is tested and is working fine :

```
@PostMapping(consumes=MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)  
public void fileUpload (@RequestParam MultipartFile file){

        ByteArrayInputStream bis=new  ByteArrayInputStream(file.getBytes());        

        try(BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bis))){          
        long count = br.lines().count();
        System.out.println(">>> total lines : "+count);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not read the line count since , it is not the file it is bytestream you are getting. if you have to read line count then create the tempfile , read it using Bufferreader and then delete the file through code only.

Comment: Thank you Ishant.

Comment: You don't need a file, or `File`, to get the line count.